# Symfony2 Forms Without a Class

Tags: forms, symfony

I am following this [tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class) and all I am trying to do is to make a simple form. I have custom bootstrapped Symfony2 components ( I am basically using almost everything without the FrameworkBundle ) so i have a code like this:

```
$defaultData = array('message' => 'Type your message here');
       $form = Forms::createFormFactory()->createBuilder($defaultData)
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('message', 'textarea')
        ->add('send', 'submit')
        ->getForm();
```

You can see the only difference is how I am obtaining the formfactory instance. 
 Here is what I am getting though as an error:

> Uncaught exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException' with
>   message 'Expected argument of type "string,
>   Symfony\Component\Form\ResolvedFormTypeInterface or
>   Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface", "array" given' in

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: If you're following the tutorial, why are you using `Forms::createFormFactory()->createBuilder($defaultData)` and NOT `$this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)`?

Comment: I am reading the tutorial to get the idea, as I said i am custom boostrapping the components. However if you read the Controller the method does this $this->container->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $data, $options); , which is basically invoking the Form Factory service , i believe this would be equal to Forms::createFormFactory() , and then it invokes createBuilder ( check my code ) so I can't see where the difference is.

Comment: Suggest starting here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html#creating-a-simple-form where it talks about a standalone components.  Get the example to work then maybe add some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You are not following the tutorial as described. The [`Forms::createBuilder()` method](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactoryInterface.html#method_createBuilder) wants to know what type of form you're creating in the first argument, not the default options. The default options are meant for the 2nd parameter in this context. You can see the difference when you [examine the `createFormBuilder` method](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_createFormBuilder) in the `Controller` API docs.

You should use the `createFormBuilder()` helper method in the tutorial as it passes proper arguments to the `createBuilder()` method internally on your behalf:

```
$defaultData = array('message' => 'Type your message here');
       $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('message', 'textarea')
        ->add('send', 'submit')
        ->getForm();
```

Or something like this should work if you insist on doing it your way:

```
// ...
$form = Forms::createFormFactory()->createBuilder('form', $defaultData)
// ...
```

Comment: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType::setDefaultOptions() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver given,   Obviously I have tried that aleady, and its not working